# Totalhours method displays minutes in wrong format

Tags: c#, .net

I have the below code which displays the totalhours, but the totalhours displays it differently for values less than 60 mins. That is for 35 mins or 45 mins (greater than 30mins) it displays as .533 and .75 respectively, and when I apply `Convert.ToInt32()` on these values it rounds it off to 1 which I don't want.

```
int imins = 31; 
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(imins);           
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32( ts.TotalHours) +":" + ts.Minutes); //string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", 
Console.Read();
```

My intention is to display the time in format example hh:mm , but if I use total hours .lets say for displaying 31 mins the output I get is 01:31 which is wrong, it should be 00:31.

Total hours should only display the totalhours minus the minutes.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? As of .NET 4, you can just specify the format when you call `ToString` on a TimeSpan. Why are you trying to use `TotalHours` at all? And the code you've given *won't* display ".75" because you're calling `Convert.ToInt32`...

Comment: Right - added an answer. There's no need to do all this formatting by hand.

Answer (score 2):

As you're using .NET 4, you can make your life *much* simpler by using [`TimeSpan.ToString(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992632.aspx) to do the formatting for you:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int minutes = 31; 
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
        string text = ts.ToString("h':'mm");
        Console.WriteLine(text); // 0:31
    }
}
```

EDIT: If you need it to go into multiple days but still only show the hours, I'm not sure that `TimeSpan` handles that. You can use a simple cast to `int` in that case:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int minutes = 31; 
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes);
        string text = string.Format("{0}:{1:mm}", (int) ts.TotalHours, ts);
        Console.WriteLine(text); // 0:31
    }
}
```

Or use my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library, which *does* support this:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Duration duration = Duration.FromMinutes(6000);
        var pattern = DurationPattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("H:mm");
        string text = pattern.Format(duration);
        Console.WriteLine(text); // 0:31
    }
}
```

(That's assuming you want the output for 100 hours to be 100:00 rather than something like 4:04:00.)

Comment: your code may not display correct value if minutes = 6000 that is hours is greater than 99.

Comment: Well what do you want the result to be in that case? (Your question doesn't say much about what you expect the range of values to be, or what the required output is.)

Answer (score 1):

use `Math.Truncate()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()` on `ts.TotalHours` it calculates the integral part of a specified double-precision floating-point number.

```
 int imins = 31; 
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(imins);           
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours) + ":" + ts.Minutes  );            //string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", 
            Console.Read();
```

if you want to an output like this `00:31` you can just

```
int imins = 31;
            TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(imins);
            Console.WriteLine(Math.Truncate(ts.TotalHours).ToString().PadLeft(2,'0') + ":" +  ts.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2,'0'));            //string.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}", 
            Console.Read();
```

Comment: You are using Math.Truncate() instead of Convert.ToInt32(). This is right, but the description is misleading. Oh, and the second part shouldn't be "TotalMinutes" because that's a large value.

Comment: Your code uses `Math.Truncate` where the OP uses `Convert.ToInt32`. This is right. But you write "Use `Math.Truncate()` instead of `ts.TotalHours`" in your text.

Comment: ah :)  ok  sorry for this

Comment: Now it looks better and gets +1 from me :-)

Comment: why not `ts.ToString()` and then truncate last colon if not required?

Comment: because totalhours may be greater than  99

Answer (score 0):

I have applied it this way using .Net 3.5

```
int imins = 31;    
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(imins);  
string sHours = ts.Hours.ToString();

if (sHours.Length == 1)
  sHours = "0" + sHours;

string sMinutes = ts.Minutes.ToString();

if (sMinutes.Length == 1)
  sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;

Console.WriteLine(sHours + ":" + sMinutes);
Console.Read();
```